# Use Upper-Case letter for the first and second characters of controller name Yii2

Tags: php, regex, yii2, url-routing

I am using `Yii2` framework and based on some standards I have to customize my controller name.

As you know the standard for controller name in yii2 is like this:

If you name your controller like this :`DServicesController`, The route in pretty url for accessing this controller's actions is `/d-services/[actionName]`.

But I want to name my controller in a way that I can access it like this in the url:

`/DServices/[action name]`

I added the following code to my `urlManager rules` but didn't work:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [
        'manage/DServices/*' => 'manage/d-services/<action>'
     ],
]
```

How can I name my controller class or define specific rule to access it like this.

P.S: As Yii2 standard the first letter of your controller name always changes to Lower-Case.

Comment: read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#routing (Named Parameters). It looks you are missing the named parameter's definition (left => )

Answer (score 0):

Actually upper case letters works fine in Yii2 routing rules. But I see two strange things in Your snippet:

1. Asterisk in route template. Did You want to pass parameters this way?
2. `manage/` prefix in action route. It will work if your controller is in `manage` module.

I tried to use Your template with these things fixed:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [
        'manage/DServices' => 'd-services/<action>'
     ],
]
```

and it works as expected.

See this section of Yii2 docs for details: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#routing